# How to see all attributes of all duplicants?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I can't figure out how to see all the attributes for all the people, there is a skill tree for all, but attributes seems to be not available.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Skills tab

You can hover your mouse over duplicants, like this:

[image]

#### Priorities tab

The same, you need to hover over them, also higher attributes will be darker purple. Unfortunately you can't sort dupes by them.

[image]

In Launch Update, there are no menus to display skills as numbers for everyone. Priorities tab is the closest to it.

I didn't find any setting that affects pop-up delays or something. If you can't get attributes by hovering, this is probably a bug.